# height of TD automatically resizing even though it is set to a fixed size

Tags: html, css

I have a table in the middle of my website: [www.care.dti.dk](http://care.dti.dk)

The first `<tr>` of the table which is wrapped around the div: `#pricingTable` has a height of 5px.

On localhost it works fine, but when i put it online, the browser automatically resizes the height to 15px, which makes the background image repeat.

I've tried setting `background-repeat: no-repeat;` but this doesnt place the image in the buttom, where i would like it to be.

What is causing this problem, and how do i fix it?

Comment: I see it OK. It could be the browser cache.

Comment: use css to style your elements instead of using html attributes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this CSS :

```
    #pricingTable table tr:first-child td {
         font-size:0;
         height:5px;
     }
```

and remove html element `height="5px"` in your `td`

and now you write `<td height="5px">` **this is not correct** if you write height in `td`

than `<td height="5">` **this**

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&nbsp;` inside the `<td>`

or

Add another CSS attr: `line-height: 5px`